# Input a comma after every 10 digit in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I put 10 digit mobile numbers in a Textarea like the follwoing.
242452354643663463636346366363463636365636363634656346
but i need to put comma(,) after every 10 digit number.

Comment: any example of input and output string?

Comment: I'm a little unclear if you want to validate that there's a comma after every 10 digits, or insert one automatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
"242452354643663463636346366363463636365636363634656346".replace(/(\d{10})/g,"$1,")

// 2424523546,4366346363,6346366363,4636363656,3636363465,6346
```

Comment: Yes like that..Which javascript event would be better we prefer Keyup?

Comment: can u explain in detail?what is g?what is $1?

Comment: @Hari kanna, `/(\d{10})/` is a [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), with 10 continuous digits, and `$1` means, matched 10 digits in the bracket `(` 10 digits  `)`, add comma after all matched instances. Basically, replacing 10 digits with 10 digits + ","

Answer (score 1):

Above solution did not help with splitting a 10 digit phone number being typed into for example a textarea.
My solution: 1. your text area should be validated to return only numbers onKeyPress.

then

```
function commafyPhone(str){
    var newStr='';
    if(str.length>10){
        var str_array=str.split(",");
        for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
            newStr+=str_array[i].replace(/(\d{10})/g,'$1,');
        }
        return newStr;
    }
    return str;
}
```

On the textarea form field, i used:

```
onKeyUp="this.value=commafyPhone(this.value);"
```

However, my solution requires to remove the comma on your last number entered.

Comment: how can i remove ',' from end?